# Is this "double nature" trait in line with other Pathfinder traits?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, homebrew-review, traits

So I have half-elf druid of [Gozreh](http://pathfinder.wikia.com/wiki/Gozreh) - deity with double nature as a goddess of beach fun and god of storm's wrath. I promised my players bonus traits for character history and knacks. What I came up for her is this:

> ## Double nature
>
> (mixed races only, follower of deity with multiple natures)
>
> Once a day, you can assume look of either of your parents races. This does not change your physical or mental traits, your dexterity, strength, senses or anything, just your body look. Your characteristic features remain unchanged. You get +5 trait bonus on disguise tests to pretend you are pure blood of chosen race, and +1 trait bonus on disguise tests against people looking specifically for you. You can keep this form as long as you want, or revert to your original form. This is 0-level spell-like divine transmutation.

Reasoning: +1 trait bonus on two skills (like [Partial Protege](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/partial-protege)) or +2 to two skills, but with limited application ([Perfectionist's brew](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/perfectionist-s-brew)) are known. This trait would affect only one skill, with +1 or +5 (but limited) bonus, and would be subject to detect magic etc.

I want to be sure - is it fair? And if not, how to tweak it?

Comment: I would make sure that your players are clear on what "Your characteristic features remain unchanged" means - it's not immediately obvious from the text.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's fine as is - the bonus is so situational and narrow that it's certainly less powerful than the ever popular "+1 to init" traits. You could ask whether it's good enough, but I assume some set of situations in your game makes this specific trait desirable enough to the player that we're having this conversation (elf/human friction?).

If you just want a one-way "pass as" trait then just adapt the half-orc trait [Almost Human](http://d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/almost-human).

Comment: "+1 to init"? The usual trait I think of for this is Reactionary, which gives +2.